# Search in image (haystack) by providing shape (needle) with relaxed parameters?

Tags: windows, images, adobe-photoshop

I have, for example, this image (could be any other image with any other black lines):

[image]

I want to find a match that is a exact or almost match in the above image by providing, for example, the following image:

[image]

Now I would like it to show me where a potential match is found, for example like this:

[image]

I don't know how to describe this nor how to search for this on google.

How can I do this in photoshop (or in windows if not in photoshop) (/ or what search terms could help me research my options)?

Comment: Photoshop is an image editing program, what makes you think something like this is possible in PS? I don't think it is.

Comment: Maybe because it's scriptable, but okay, other programs are allowed too, it's just I don't really know what to search for so I am asking here (because mostly I will google the hell out of a problem and look at 1000+ sites until I give up).

Comment: Okay, I thought maybe you'd seen something similar done in PS. I don't have a solution for you, but the key term to search for is "computer vision". Here are some relevant SO questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2430317/1832306 "How can I use computer vision to find a shape in an image?"), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2074956/1832306 "Logo recognition in images")